# How do I run a python script in parallel with different arguments in linux?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, parallel-processing

I have a Python script that takes in an argument like so.

```
conda activate base
python myScript.py arg1
```

I’m connected to my server over ssh so there will be no window system. I want to run 5 different with my script in parallel. So like,

```
#!/bin/bash
conda activate base
for i in arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
do
  python myScript.py $i
done
```

But this would only let the code run one after the other. How do I run it in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel python myScript.py ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

**GNU Parallel** can also do the `ssh` to one, or more servers for you, so you don't need to login:

```
parallel -S server 'conda activate base; python myScript.sh' ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

Also, add a shebang as the first line of your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and make your script executable like this:

```
chmod +x myScript.py
```

then you can stop telling your shell to use Python every time you want to run it and just use:

```
./myScript.py arg
```

Comment: is there a way to do this so that I can see the outputs of the scripts that are running in different screens using the screen function?

Comment: i tried your command but it says your shell has not been properly configured to use conda activate

Answer (score 1):

You could execute them in the background using `&`:

```
for i in arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
do
  python myScript.py $i &
  # Here ---------------^
done
```